# How to write proof of the fact that the torus with a point removed is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sum of two circles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have been trying to prove that the torus $T$ with any point$\{x\}$ removed is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sum of two circles. Now I have the intuitive idea of the result, I can see how we can continuously deform $T\setminus \{x\}$ into $S^1\vee S^1$. I have found that this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842672/proving-homotopy-equivalence-of-a-torus-with-points-removed) has been asked before, but the answers use diagrams to prove the statement. But if I wanted a concrete proof of the fact how would I go about it?

From the definition of homotopy equivalence we want two continuous maps $f:T\setminus \{x\}\to S^1\vee S^1$ and $g:S^1\vee S^1\to T\setminus \{x\}$ such that $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are both homotopic to the identity. I believe this $f,g$ should be somewhat canonical, but I can't guess what I should write here. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: See the following question for a picture: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1842672/29059

Comment: That's the thing I understand the picture. But it's not a real proof is it. I wanted to know how to write a proper proof.

Comment: While I understand what you mean by "it's not a real proof" in the sense that it does not include all details, I would contend that it *is* a proof. You'll find in your studies, especially in topology, that 'proof by picture' is often the best way to go about proving something. As long as you have a sufficient understanding of what's going on in the background, I would argue that it is just as rigorous a proof as any strange piece-wise continuous function that you have to describe (which can just about be done in this case with some care, but for more difficult examples would be impossible).

Comment: Haha I see. Well that clears things up a lot. Because I can see the picture more or less but it was getting confusing writing the proof down completely. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a somewhat different point of view on the role of pictures: they are intuitive devices that we humans *can use* to construct rigorous proofs, and to communicate our proofs. The idea is to use the picture as an intuitive guideline to write down the function of your desire, and then to *prove* that this function does what it is supposed to do, i.e. in your case that it is a deformation retract. To carry this out rigorously, you must write actual formulas for your functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write the torus as a closed square with opposite edges identified.
Take the square's centre as the point to be removed. Deform the
square minus its centre radially to its perimeter. When we identify the edges
this becomes a deformation retraction of the torus minus a point to a bouquet
of two circles.