# Deforming the torus without a point to $S^1 \lor S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-writing, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Let $T$ be the topological torus, given by taking a rectangle with parallel sides oriented in the same direction, and glueing together each pair of parallel sides along the given direction.

> Take a point $P\in T$ and remove it, I want to show that $S^1 \lor S^1$ is
> a deformation retract of $T-\{P\}$ which is given by glueing two
> circles at some point.

Intuitively:

- The point $P$ divides the inner area of the rectangle in four parts, those points lying above $P$ or below $P$, and left and right of $P$.
- These parts will be the triangles delimited by the segments connecting the point $P$ to the vertices.
- Now I can define a retraction collapsing each point of the rectangle to the corresponding point on the base of the triangle it belongs to.
  This is not well defined for points lying on the segments connecting $P$ to the vertices, but each choice will give some retraction, and the retraction will be homotopic to the identity because the rectangle is a convex set (**edit**: I think this point is wrong, because if I remove a point I lose the convexity).
- So we have produced a retraction of the rectangle onto its sides.
- Passing to the quotient which identifies the parallel sides, this composition is still a retraction if we quotient also the rectangle by the same relation making it a torus.
- We conclude by observing that quotienting the boundary of the rectangle by the above relation gives a space homeomorphic to two circles glued at a point, and we are done.

> Can we make this argument more rigorous?
>
> What I am not satisfied about my argument is that it does not make
> clear why it is important to remove a point from the torus. What is a
> rigorous way to make clear that removing a point is necessary to make
> this argument work?

My **main question** is:

> Where precisely in the argument above am I using the fact that I removed the point $P$?

Comment: Related: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3361794/how-to-write-proof-of-the-fact-that-the-torus-with-a-point-removed-is-homotopy-e), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842672/proving-homotopy-equivalence-of-a-torus-with-points-removed)

Comment: Consider $T^2$ as a quotient of the disc modulo an identification on its boundary. Note that $\partial D^2$ is a deformation retract of $D^2\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @Tyrone Sorry Im not understanding what you want to tell me

Comment: The deformation retract fixes the boundary pointwise at all times. Since the relations to produce $T^2$ only occur on the boundary of $D^2$, the homotopy factors over the quotient to give a deformation retraction of $T^2\setminus\{p\}$ onto $S^1\vee S^1$, the latter space being what is produced by the identifications on $\partial D^2$.

Comment: @Tyrone Are you calling $T^2$ what I call $T?$ Or is $T^2=T \times T$? If $R$ is the rectangle, the relation to produce $T$ is a subset of $R ^2.$  I still do not understand almost nothing in your comment, my bad for sure

Comment: I'm writing $T^2$ for what you are calling $T$. The notation is often used interchangably, sorry to confuse you (I'll write $T$ from now on). $T$ is a quotient of the square $[0,1]^2$ by a relation which identifies points on its boundary. Since $[0,1]^2\cong D^2$ by a homeomorphism which restricts to $\partial [0,1]^2\cong \partial D^2$, we can also think of $T$ as a quotient of $D^2$ by a relation which identifies points on its boundary. The map $(D^2\setminus0)\times I\rightarrow D^2\setminus 0$, $(z,t)\mapsto (1-t)\cdot z+t\frac{z}{|z|}$, is a deformation retract onto $\partial D^2$.

Comment: It factors over the quotient to give a map $(T\setminus p)\times I\rightarrow T\setminus p$ which is a deformation onto $S^1\vee S^1$.

Comment: @Tyrone So, if I understand correctly, for any choice of $P$ I can find a homeomorphism $[0,1]^2-{P} \simeq D^2 - 0,$ then I deform $D^2-0$ onto $\partial D^2$ and here it's clear why I have to remove $0,$ and then I pass to the quotient.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. It is still not clear where I use the fact that I remove $P$ in my argument in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111624/discussion-between-tyrone-and-ggeolier).

Comment: Your wording is off: You want to show that $S^1 \wedge S^1$ is a deformation retract of $T - \{P\}$, not the other way around.

Comment: @LeeMosher you are right, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me answer your main question by first considering a different situation.

**Deforming the sphere $S^2$ with a point to a point:** Take a point $P \in S^2$ and remove it, and show that what's left deformation retracts to a point. To do this let's choose $P$ to be the north pole $P=(0,0,1)$, and we'll define a deformation retraction of $S^2 - \{P\}$ to the south pole $Q = (0,0,-1)$.

Intuitively, the deformation restriction moves each point of $S^2 - \{P\}$ southward, along the longitude line through that point, to the south pole $Q$.

*Where precisely in this argument did we use the fact that we removed the point $P$?*

There is no well-defined longitude line through the north pole; in some sense the north pole lies on *every* longitude line. Thus, we had to remove the north pole before our deformation retraction could be well-defined.

*What is a rigorous way of doing this?*

Use spherical coordinates in $\mathbb R^3$, whose required properties, including apprpriate continuity properties, are known to you from your knowledge and expertise of analytic geometry. Using spherical coordinates, write down a formula for the deformation retraction
$$h : (S^2 - \{P\}) \times [0,1] \to S^2 - \{P\}
$$
The formula for $h$ that you write down should have the effect that the latitude coordinate (usually in $[0,2\pi]$, with $0$ and $2\pi$ identified) does not change as the time parameter $t \in [0,1]$ increases from $0$ to $1$. But the longitude coordinate (usually in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ with $-\pi/2$ as the south pole and $+\pi/2$ as the north pole) should decrease at constant speed from its initial value in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, moving along its latitude line to the final value $-\pi/2$.

Notice: the north pole had to be omitted because it does not lie on a well-defined longitude, and so there is no way to extend the formula for $h$ continuously. Intuitively, we cannot continuously choose a longitude line along which the north pole moves down toward the south pole. While it's also true that the longitude line at the south pole is not well-defined, the south pole *does not move* under the deformation retraction.

**But**,  for full rigor you must actually write down the formula for $h$, and check all of its the required properties for the desired deformation retraction.

---

Now, on to the torus.

Model the torus $T$ as the quotient of the square $R = [-1,+1] \times [-1,+1]$ with respect to the equivalence relation generated by $(x,-1) \sim (x,+1)$ and $(-1,y) \sim (+1,y)$. In place of cylindrical or spherical coordinates in $S^2$, use radial coordinates on the square $R$. Its boundary $\partial R$ is the union of the four sides $\{-1\} \times [-1,+1]$, $\{+1\} \times [-1,+1]$, $[-1,+1] \times \{-1\}$, $[-1,+1] \times \{+1\}$. We are going to remove the point $\mathcal O = (0,0)$. Using our knowledge and expertise in plane analytic geometry, each point $x \in R - \{\mathcal O\}$ can be written uniquely in the form
$$r(x) \cdot b(x)
$$
where
\begin{align*}
r(x) &= \frac{1}{\max\{x_1,x_2\}} \\
b(x) = \frac{x}{r(x)}
\end{align*}
We have removed the point $\mathcal O$ in order that these expressions $r(x)$ and $b(x)$ be well-defined and continuous as functions of $x \in R - \mathcal O$.

Now use the coordinates to define the formula for the deformation retraction
$$h : (R - \mathcal O) \times [0,1] \to R - \mathcal O
$$
Intuitively, the formula for $h$ keeps the boundary coordinate $b(x)$ constant, whereas the "radial" coordinate increases linearly from its initial value $r(x) \in (0,1]$ to its final value $1$, as $x$ moves outward along its radial segment towards $\partial R$.

Notice: the central point $\mathcal O$ had to be removed, because it does not lie on a well-defined radial segment and therefore there is no way to extend $h$ continuously. Now, under the identification of $\partial R$ to a wedge of two circles, a point in that wedge does not correspond to a well-defined point of $\partial R$, instead it correspond to either $2$ or $4$ points of $\partial R$; however, this does not matter because those points do not move under the deformation retraction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, very clear and carefully written. So you are confirming my fear that for such arguments there is no way of giving a purely topological rigorous proof without having to use coordinates?

Comment: *[Shrug]* What's wrong with coordinates? The properties of Cartesian coordinate space are the foundation of topology, after all.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have nothing against coordinates

Answer (score 2):

I think everything has been resolved in the comments already, but here is a bit more information. The main point is that a two-dimensional square with its centre removed can be deformation retracted onto its perimeter, see for instance the [linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3361794/how-to-write-proof-of-the-fact-that-the-torus-with-a-point-removed-is-homotopy-e) by Angina Seng. The details of how this is accomplished aren't too important. For instance, Tyrone outlined in the comments how to do this by first identifying the square with the disk. Just for the purposes of providing another perspective, here is an approach you could use to get things down to the level of formulas without passing from the square to the Euclidean disk.

Let $(X,\| \cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space. Let $B = \{ x \in X : \|x\| \leq 1\}$ be the closed unit ball and $S= \{x \in X: \|x\|=1\}$ the unit sphere. Its quite straightforward to give a homotopy $f_t:B \setminus \{0\} \to B \setminus \{0\}$ deforming the identity map of the punctured ball into the "normalization map" $x \mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|} : B \setminus \{0\} \to S$ while keeping the points of $S$ fixed. Just divide a vector $x$ by a factor which continuously changes from $1$ to $\|x\|$, say
$$f_t(x) = \frac{x}{1-t + t\|x\|}.$$
It is important to see that the normalization map does not extend to the whole ball, since one gets a division by zero in that case. Removing a point is crucial to getting the retraction.

Now, taking $X= \mathbb{R}^2$ and using the $\infty$-norm
$$\|x\|_\infty = \max(|x_1|,|x_2|)$$
one has that the ball and sphere are, respectively, the 2-dimensional square of side length 2 centred at $0$ and the perimeter of that square, so above procedure applies to this case, in particular.

Comment: I don't understand why "the details of how it is accomplished are not too important". I encounter too many proofs in topology where vague and pictorial arguments are given, and frankly I hate them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, which is useful

Comment: For example, in the argument I gave in my question, I say at some point "the retraction is homotopic to the identity because the rectangle is convex" but actually I think I made a mistake! Because the rectangle minus a point is not convex, so it's not even clear to me how to prove that the retraction is homotopic to the identity by using an argument like the one of Agina Seng or mine, while it's clear with an argument like Tyron's or the one you propose.

Comment: By "the details of how it is accomplished are not too important" I just mean the specific homotopy chosen does not matter at the end. There are infinitely many ways of deformation retracting the punctured square to its boundary and two different people might approach the problem differently. At the end of of the day it is not important which homotopy is used, only that some homotopy exists.

Comment: ah well in this sense I agree of course. What I was saying is that for example the argument in Angina Seng answer never actually proves existence of a homotopy.

Comment: @ggeolier:  While I agree that, to a beginner, the "details of how it is accomplished" can be important, once you become more comfortable with these kind of things, you'll likely switch your viewpoint to "yes, I could construct and explicit deformation, but I wouldn't learn much from doing it".  This is analogous to the fact that, in principle, every mathematical proof can be reduced to a sequence of statements in first order logic.  In practice, mathematicians simply learn to recognize a proof, without worrying about those logically underpinnings.

Comment: @JasonDeVito But here the only two important things to prove are: that the retraction is continuous, and the existence of the homotopy. I agree 100% that writing an explicit deformation is useless, but then you have to prove its existence in some way, don't you? The pictorial argument does not skip details, it only gives the details which are already obvious while omitting the only two important things. I have already seen proofs in algebra or analysis which skip details, and its completely fine to me, but I have never encountered a situation like the one I'm seeing in topology "visual proofs"

Comment: @JasonDeVito If you care to give a proof you should prove the nontrivial things, if you just say "it's like this because it's like this", and make a picture, you can save time and write no proof at all, because it's the same. So I thank you for your comment but I do not agree at all that it's the same thing as "skipping logical steps", it's a completely different attitude which I have never seen anywhere except topology. Sorry for the rant.

Comment: @ggeolier:  No need to apologize for the rant.  I agree that for this exercise, the whole point is to construct the deformation retract, and so it needs to be done in quite explicit detail.  I also agree that if you're going go prove something, you should focus on the non-trivial parts.  What I'm claiming is that as you go further into algebraic topology, you'll often view constructing the deformations (or, at least, proving the existence of a such a deformation) as the trivial part.

Comment: @MikeF thanks for your answer; I upvoted it, but I decided to accept the one of Lee Mosher